# C++ Efficient Growing Vector of Fix-Sized Vector

Tags: c++

In my program, I had a `std::vector<std::array<float, n_channels>> vecvec`, where `n_channels` was a constant integer known at compile time.  In the program, `vecvec` grows over time.

I now want to lift the constraint that `n_channels` must be known at compile time, so I changed the definition to `std::vector<std::vector<float>> vecvec`.    `n_channels` is still a fixed value, which is known before `vecvec` is constructed (all elements of `vecvec` have the same length).

However, now my program is suddenly about 2.5x slower.

I assume this is because the memory of `vecvec` is suddenly fragmented, because it doesn't "know" that every element of vecvec will have the same size.

Is there a way I can have my cake and eat it too?

Comment: do you reserve enough space upfront?

Comment: can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: btw if every element of `vecvec` has the same size then a `std::vector<std::vector<float>>` is probably the wrong data structure. Consider to use a flat `std::vector<float>` instead

Comment: Release build with no iterator debugging? Have you profiled? What compiler/platform?

Comment: It's hard to tell why your program runs slower because you didn't provide any code. My guess is, it has something to do with [push_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) overhead. As @formerlyknownas_463035818 suggested, you can remove most of this overhead by using the [reserve](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) function

Comment: Sounds about right. std::array is really good at what it does. Shouldn't be an issue unless it gets more slower for bigger sizes.

Comment: The overhead was likely due to the increased number of dynamic allocations, and the poor cache locality resulting from the second layer of pointer indirection (where to access an element it has to do two deferences, instead of a dereference and a multiplication)

Comment: What is 2.5x slower? Constructing the vector of vectors or accessing elements of it?

Answer (score 2):

### Do you want to have your cake and eat it too? Implement your own row-resizable 2D array class TODAY!!!

You can write your own 2D array class. By making rows contiguous in memory, you get all the benefits of using `std::vector<std::array<...>>`, but without the fixed compiletime sizes! To simplify the implementation, you can make it wrap `std::vector`.

In order to achieve full functionality, we should also create two "helper" classes. One of them represents a row in the array, and the other represents an iterator for that row. When we iterate through the 2D array, we'll be iterating over the rows of the array.

#### Row class

This is pretty straight-forward. It just contains a beginning and end pointer. The array is stored contiguously, so we don't actually store `Row`s, but it's still convenient to have them so we have a type to iterate over.

Because the `Row` class just represents a view of a row in the matrix, **the `Row` class should NOT allocate or delete any memory.** Additionally, I made all the member functions of the `Row` class constant so that operations can be performed on `Row`s returned directly from the `RowIterator`.

```
template<class T>
struct Row {
    T* _start;
    size_t _size;
    // These are const because if we need the elements to be const
    // We just make T const
    T* begin() const noexcept { return _start; }
    T* end() const noexcept { return _start + _size; }
    size_t size() const noexcept { return _size; }
    T& operator[](size_t index) const noexcept {
        return _start[index]; 
    }
    // Implicitly convertible to Row<T const>
    operator Row<T const>() const noexcept {
        return {_start, _size}; 
    }
};
```

#### RowIterator class

This one just implements the basic abilities of a random-access iterator. You can move it forward, backward, index into it, add or subtract integers from it, etc. If I subtract 5, for example, it moves back 5 rows.

```
template<class T>
struct RowIterator {
    using value_type = Row<T>; 
    using element_type = Row<T>; 
    using reference_type = Row<T>; 
    using const_reference_type = Row<T>;
    // Add other iterator traits as needed  


    Row<T> current; 
    void operator++() noexcept {
        current._start += current._size; 
    }
    void operator--() noexcept {
        current._start -= current._size; 
    }
    RowIterator<T> operator+(intptr_t rows) const noexcept {
        return { Row<T>{current._start + rows * current._size, current._size } }; 
    }
    RowIterator<T> operator-(intptr_t rows) const noexcept {
        return { Row<T>{current._start - rows * current._size, current._size } }; 
    }
    RowIterator<T>& operator+=(intptr_t rows) noexcept {
        current._start += rows * current._size; 
        return *this; 
    }
    RowIterator<T>& operator-=(intptr_t rows) noexcept {
        current._start -= rows * current._size; 
        return *this; 
    }
    Row<T> operator*() const noexcept {
        return current; 
    }
    bool operator==(RowIterator<T> other) const noexcept {
        return current._start == other.current._start && current._size == other.current._size; 
    }
    bool operator!=(RowIterator<T> other) const noexcept {
        return current._start != other.current._start || current._size != other.current._size; 
    }
    Row<T> operator[](intptr_t index) {
        return (*this + index).current; 
    }
};
```

#### vector2D class

The 2D vector class stores it's elements contiguously in a vector, but to access them or iterator over them it returns `Row`s and `RowIterator`s. Because a `Row` is just two values (a pointer and a size), this is really cheap to do, and the compiler should be able to optimize it easily.

Note that to preserve const correctness, I use `Row<T const>`, which creates a `Row` with constant elements. (This greatly simplifies the implementation of `Row`).

```
template<class T>
class vector2D : private std::vector<T> {
    size_t rows; 
    size_t columns; 
    using std::vector<T>::data; 

   public:
    size_t size() const noexcept {
        return rows; 
    }
    // Gets a particular row
    Row<T> operator[](size_t index) noexcept {
        return { data() + columns * index, columns }; 
    }
    // Get a particular row when const
    Row<T const> operator[](size_t index) const noexcept {
        return { data() + columns * index, columns }; 
    }
    RowIterator<T> begin() noexcept {
        return { Row<T>{ data() , columns } }; 
    }
    RowIterator<T> end() noexcept { 
        return { Row<T>{ data() + columns * rows, columns } }; 
    }
    RowIterator<T const> begin() const noexcept {
        return { Row<T const>{ data() , columns } }; 
    }
    RowIterator<T const> end() const noexcept { 
        return { Row<T const>{ data() + columns * rows, columns } }; 
    }

    template<size_t N>
    void push_back(std::array<T, N> const& arr) {
        if(arr.size() == columns) {
            insert(end(), arr.begin(), arr.end()); 
            rows++; 
        }
        else
            throw std::invalid_argument("Bad number of columns"); 
    }

    void push_back(Row<T> arr) {
        if(arr.size() == columns) {
            insert(end(), arr.begin(), arr.end()); 
            rows++; 
        }
        else
            throw std::invalid_argument("Bad number of columns"); 
    }
    void push_back(Row<T const> arr) {
        if(arr.size() == columns) {
            insert(end(), arr.begin(), arr.end()); 
            rows++; 
        }
        else
            throw std::invalid_argument("Bad number of columns"); 
    }
    void push_back(std::initializer_list<T> arr) {
        if(arr.size() == columns) {
            insert(end(), arr.begin(), arr.end()); 
            rows++; 
        }
        else
            throw std::invalid_argument("Bad number of columns"); 
    }
    vector2D(size_t rows, size_t columns)
        : std::vector<T>(rows * columns)
        , rows(rows)
        , columns(columns) {}

};
```

### Benchmark results

[**Run the benchmark here**](http://quick-bench.com/vD4RFNSQa15slc40ENv2TJ4hPTI)

The benchmark results are in, and `vector2D` is just as fast as using a vector of arrays!!!

#### The test

The test has two parts:

- Fill the 2D array with values
- Sum all the values

To make things as general as possible, these are the functions I used. They can be used with `std::vector<std::vector<...>>`, `std::vector<std::array<...>>`, or our very own `vector2D`!

```
template<class List>
auto calculateSum2D(List const& list) {
  using elem_t = std::decay_t<decltype(list[0][0])>;
  elem_t initial = 0;

  for(auto const& row : list) {
    for(auto& elem : row) {
      initial += elem;
    }
  }
  return initial;
}

template<class List>
void fill(List& list, int rows, int cols) {
  for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      list[i][j] = i * j; 
    }
  }
}
```

#### The results

We used Quickbench to obtain the results, and `vector2D` was **4.5** times faster than using a vector of vectors!

[image]

These results were obtained using the corresponding functions, written using quick bench!

```
// Benchmark using a vector of vectors
static void sumVector(benchmark::State& state) {
  // Code inside this loop is measured repeatedly
  for (auto _ : state) {
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> vect(rows, std::vector<double>(cols));
    fill(vect, rows, cols); 

    auto sum = calculateSum2D(vect); 
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(sum);
  }
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(sumVector);

// Benchmark using a vector of arrays
static void sumArray(benchmark::State& state) {
  // Code inside this loop is measured repeatedly
  for (auto _ : state) {
    std::vector<std::array<double, cols>> vect(rows, std::array<double, cols>());
    fill(vect, rows, cols); 

    auto sum = calculateSum2D(vect); 
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(sum);
  }
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(sumArray);

// Benchmark using vector2D implementation
static void sumvector2D(benchmark::State& state) {
  // Code inside this loop is measured repeatedly
  for (auto _ : state) {
    vector2D<double> vect(rows, cols);
    fill(vect, rows, cols); 

    auto sum = calculateSum2D(vect); 
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(sum);
  }
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(sumvector2D);
```

#### Benchmarks v2: no repeated allocation

[**View benchmark 2 here**](http://quick-bench.com/qPXODfeDSErMPNtt9vyEd0iRVDc)

As it turns out, in the initial benchmark, most of the cost came from repeated allocations (in all cases, the object was re-allocated each iteration of the benchmark). To fix this, I moved the declaration out of the loop, so that it'd only occur once. I also adjusted the number of rows and columns so that there were more rows and fewer columns, so as to get a more realistic scenario where not the entire thing fits in the cache.

Once again, `vector2D` and `vector<array>` perform nearly identically, however this time `vector<vector>` does a much better job, and the gap is not nearly so impressive.

The reason for the difference in speedup is that this time around, the only differences were the result of poor cache locality, as each object was only being allocated once.

[image]

#### Summary

Based on the benchmark results, `vector2D` should bump your performance back up to what it was originally. Because your code presumably contains a mix of allocations and usage, you got a result somewhere between the two benchmarks (2.5 times slower for vector of vector). Because `vector2D` is contiguous and avoids the repeated heap allocations that plagued the vector-of-vector approach, it should be just as fast as a vector of arrays.

Comment: You drive a hard bargin. I benchmarked it, and my implementation was 4.5 times faster than using a vector of vectors. The details of the benchmark are provided above, a long with a link so that you can play around with the benchmark and run it yourself!

Comment: I'll 2D your array.

Comment: Saturday night at 6 pm?

Comment: Ah damn. It'll have to be then.

Comment: It's a nice explanation.... Took almost 30 min to complete reading.. ;)